# Foreign key referencing table with composite primary key when I only need 1 column association

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, computed-column, data-versioning

So lets say we have 2 tables on SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE VersionedData (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Version INT NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_VerData]
      PRIMARY KEY (Id, Version)
)
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE PointingTable (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RefId INT NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Pnt_Ver] FOREIGN KEY (RefId)
      REFERENCES VersionedData (Id)
)
```

My idea of this relationship is when joining these 2 particular tables I only care about latest version of VersionedData table (meaning I will ALWAYS match with maximum version for specific ID value giving me exactly 1 row that I need).

Of course the code above causes error that I must reference both PK columns from PointingTable. I could add Version column for PointingTable - however I'd be stuck to that specific version even when newer one will be inserted for VersionedTable.

I'm struggling to figure out how to redesign this relationship, I've thought of computed column for PointingTable that would utilize scalar function for getting max version, but I think that would be overkill, there must be a better way.

Comment: The definition of the 1st table is invalid.. If you had tried it, it would have given an error. You cannot have 2 primary keys in a table.

Comment: Did you mean a 2-column primary key?

Comment: Sounds like a use case for temporal tables? Automatically keeps all the history in a secondary table, and only the current version of a row in the primary table.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, I meant composite primary key. My bad, edited the post now.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I gave temporal tables a shot and that is exactly what I need for my situation! Its very convenient that system manages versioning for me on updates.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative is to create an additional table

```
CREATE TABLE CurrentVersions (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Version INT
)
```

with appropriate foreign key relations to `VersionedData`. You can then have the foreign key `FK_Pnt_Ver` reference `CurrentVersions` instead.

You'll either need an extra `JOIN` to fetch the data from `VersionedData` (I assume it contains additional columns), or alternative store the data you need in `CurrentVersions` as well. In that case, you don't even need the `Version` column.

This situation is similar to how Stack Exchange stores posts and revisions. Their database looks very much like the public [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) whose schema is documented [here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232). The `Posts` table contains the current version of a post as HTML (`Body`) and the revisions are stored (as Markdown) in the `Text` column of the `PostHistory` table.